# Exclude all but a single field of an embedded document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following document:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name" : "bob",
    "alotofstuff": [],
    "morestuff",
    "item": {
        "name": "baumeister",
        "manyfieldshere": 1,
        "evenmore": 2
    }
}
```

Is there a way to return the document, without all the properties of `item` except the `name` field, like this:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name" : "bob",
    "alotofstuff": [],
    "morestuff",
    "item": {
        "name": "baumeister",
    }
}
```

I want to avoid to write a projection, that has to include all the other fields `{ name: 1, alotofstuff: 1, morestuff: 1, item.name: 1 }` (the real document is much bigger).

Comment: why don't you exclude those properties ?  are they large in number too ?

Comment: @UsmanRana yes, and there are even different kind of items

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use the [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), here's a workaround that will do what you're asking for, using [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):

```
db.your_collection.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { "item_name": "$item.name" } },
    { $project: { item: 0 } },
    { $addFields: { "item.name": "$item_name" } },
    { $project: { item_name: 0 } }
])
```

It's a simple process of creating a temporary `item_name` property, removing the `item` property, adding the `item.name` property back in from the temporary `item_name` and then finally removing the `item_name` temporary property.

I can't claim that this is a clean solution, but it's practical - I hope it helps. You can add a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage as the first pipeline stage if you want to filter the documents first (I assume you do).

Comment: This is a great use of addFields and project for a lazy man like me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Projection is only solution, if you don't want DB engine to return other keys.

Sorry!

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't want to avoid writing a projection. I want to avoid to write a very complex projection. I'm asking if there is a clever way to do this.